# inner-join mysql joining 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

i am having problems using an inner join for 3 tables..

i need to display cust_id, the customer forename and surname, the product name<-(from products table) and date of sale<--(from sales table), also i need to display in order of the most recent dates first.

this is what i have got so far

```
enter SELECT   
   customers.cust_id, 
   customers.forename, 
   customers.surname, 
   products.prod_name, 
   sales.Date_of_sale
FROM 
   customers
INNER JOIN 
   sales
ON 
   customers.cust_id = sales.cust_id; here
```

id really appreciate it if you could help me here, thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Just add one more `JOIN` to the `products` table and include an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT   
   c.cust_id, 
   c.forename, 
   c.surname, 
   p.prod_name, 
   s.Date_of_sale
FROM customers c
    INNER JOIN sales s ON c.cust_id = s.cust_id
    INNER JOIN products p ON s.product_id = p.product_id
ORDER BY s.Date_of_sale DESC
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: this doesnt work i get errors ---->
#1054 - Unknown column 's.product_id' in 'on clause'

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is in your FROM parameter. 
You specified only customer.

```
  SELECT customers.cust_id, customers.forename, customers.surname, products.prod_name,     sales.Date_of_sale
 FROM 
 customers , products , sales
 INNER JOIN 
 sales
 ON 
 customers.cust_id = sales.cust_id;
```

Comment: i'm getting  the error #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'sales'  please help